# Vertical lines in array not appearing (Chrome)

Tags: bug, mathjax, google-chrome

On the main site, in Google Chrome, the vertical lines of an array made in $\LaTeX$ do not appear. They appear in meta, but not on the main site. Here is a latex array: $$\left[\begin{array}{c|c|c|c} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\ 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \end{array}\right]$$ with the coding

> `$$\left[\begin{array}{c|c|c|c} 
>   1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
>   5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\ 
>   9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \end{array}\right]$$`

And a screenshot of the same code in the question editor on the main site:

[image: LaTeX array - vertical lines error]

Another example: 
[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/398671/151595) appears as follows for me: 
[image]

The vertical lines always appear using **Internet Explorer**, even on the main site.

Comment: It's rendering fine for me (Chrome 42.0.2311.90 under Windows 8.1).

Comment: It's weird, at first I didn't see them but they eventually appeared (chrome, windows 8). If you wait do they eventually show up?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi No

Comment: @ArthurFischer I am using version 42.0.2311.90 m in desktop mode in Windows 8.1

Comment: Rendering on FF 37, Ubuntu.

Comment: Everything is good on Chrome 42.0.2311.90 under OSX 10.10.1